# How to chang attribute of subclass based on superclass

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, inheritance

I have created class Employee:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,salary = 1500):
        self.__name = name
        self.__salary = salary
```

Then, I want to define subclass Professor, salary of which is 3*salary of Employee. But I need to change the salary of my subclass based on superclass.

```
class Professor(Employee):
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,salary)
        self.__salary = self.__salary*3
```

but it throws me an error "

```
__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'salary'"
```

How can I fixe that?

Answer (score 3):

This happens because you have set your attributes to emulate private variables by giving them a `__` prefix. Python mangles these variables and makes them hard to access from other classes. You could easily solve your problem by not making them 'private':

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,salary = 1500):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

class Professor(Employee):

    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,salary)
        self.salary = self.salary * 3
```

If you for whatever reason really need to have them be 'private' variables, you can access them in your subclass like this: `self._Employee__salary`

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,salary = 1500):
        self.__name = name
        self.__salary = salary

class Professor(Employee):

    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,salary)
        self._Employee__salary = self._Employee__salary * 3
```

If you want to have a default salary for your Professor objects, you need to explicitly add that in the `__init__` function of `Professor`:

```
class Professor(Employee):

    def __init__(self,name,salary = 1500):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,salary)
        self._Employee__salary = self._Employee__salary * 3
```

As for the question about inheriting default parameter values: You can't really do it, since you are redefining `__init__` in your `Professor` class (which makes sense, since you are extending its functionality). You can somehow work around the issue with your default parameters but it's not really pretty and I wouldn't recommend it:

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self,name,salary):
        self.__name = name
        if salary == None:
            self.__salary = 1500
        else:
            self.__salary = salary

class Professor(Employee):

    def __init__(self,name,salary = None):
        Employee.__init__(self,name,salary)
        self._Employee__salary = self._Employee__salary * 3
```

Comment: With this code you still get the same error: `__init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'salary'`. I've been trying to find a solution, but the issue is still the same, the positional `salary = 1500` doesn't carry into the `Professor` subclass, thus we still get a positional error. When creating an instance of the `Professor` class it works if you put a positional argument in, such as `tony = Professor('tony', 100)`

Comment: I don't know which of my code version you are talking about but I don't get any error.

Comment: Oh we were talking about two different errors :D Yes, the `__init__` function in Professor is not inherited from Employee. And since the `salary` argument doesn't have a default value in `Professor` you have to explicitly pass the salary value in when instantiating a Professor object.

Comment: Yep, I'm referring to your second block of code that uses private variables. Try the difference between `tony = Professor('tony', 100)` and `tony = Professor('tony')`

Comment: I'm personal curious if there is a way to inherit the positional argument since I don't know if its possible :) Plus that is the issue that the op has bumped in to.

Comment: @Keiwan Is it possible somehow to inherite __init__ from Employee to Professor?Of yes, how?

Comment: See the last edit. @Darren Haynes Yes, that's the first issue he ran into but he would have immediately run into the next one as well, after instantiating Professor correctly :)